# contraction mapping proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, banach-fixed-point

I was reading a paper, and there is a proof I don't understand.

[image]

How did they get from eq(6.4) to eq(6.5) using the norm they defined?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is the link to the paper
[RECONSTRUCTION TECHNIQUES FOR CLASSICAL
INVERSE STURM-LIOUVILLE PROBLEMS](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-197/S0025-5718-1992-1106979-0/S0025-5718-1992-1106979-0.pdf)

Comment: As written the first question is unanswerable: you have not told us what $u$ is or what equation it satisfies. For the second question, is it assumed that the variable $x$ in (6.4) is in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is in $[0,1]$  @Willie Wong

Comment: Can you provide the link to the paper?

Comment: @ArcticChar http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-197/S0025-5718-1992-1106979-0/S0025-5718-1992-1106979-0.pdf  Here is the link